# Counting decision coverage

Tags: testing, code-coverage

I was learning for the ISTQB exam and cannot solve this:

```
if (x > y)
     print (x)
else if (x < y)
     print (y)
else
     print (x,y)
```

This is said to have 3 decision and 5 branches. 3 and 5? Should I consider a branch when the first "If" is false (then "else" applies) and when the "else if" is false, when "else" applies again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 5 branches total.

```
              if
             /  \
          false true
          else 
           if
          /  \
       false true
       else 
        |
```

Comment: thanks, but is the last else really a branch? Because it is just the same branch starting with else if-false.

Comment: Yes because it is also leading to a decision taken in case a condition is matched. 3 decisions will be 1) x<y 2) x>y and 3) x==y

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Decision coverage measures possible decision outcomes - here are True and False for two IFs (4 branches). The last else is taken implicitly when the output of the else if is False without any other decision.

Comment: Try this link. It have a doc file attached in comment of Mohit. I hope it will help. http://www.testrepublic.com/forum/topics/decision-coverage?commentId=1178155%3AComment%3A59482&xg_source=activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Branch Coverage reveals, if all branches were executed. (For example, an if-instruction has two branches, the then-branch and the else-branch.)
```

In your code three decisions and 5 branches.
stmt 1 if two branches true or false
stmt 3 else if two branches true or false
stmt 5 else one branch

so pass values like
x = 2,1,2
y = 1,2,2

so that all three decisions and 5 branches are covered.

Hope this helps you